# High frequency current on straight wire

Tags: electromagnetism

To show what happens when high frequency currents travel through a wire, normally a cross section is depicted showing the skin effect.

However, I'm more interested to know what happens along the entirety of the wire. If the wire is long enough, are all the cross sections the same at all times? Or is there a time and space dependency in function of the current frequency?

I assume that if this is the case, the magnetic field created by the current will vary as well in function of time and space. Any indication on how to calculate this is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not an expert, but if "high frequency" means that the length of the "wire" is greater than the wavelength of the signal, then you might need to account for the return path and, to treat the pair of conductors as a [_transmission line_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line).

Comment: High frequency implies an alternating current. Alternating means that it changes regularly in time. Since it travels at a finite speed, that also implies alternation is space. All this is inherent in the title of your question. Is that all you mean, or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I think that Solomon Slow pointed me in the right direction. In transmission lines the effect I was talking about is taken into account. Probably I have never seen this before since it only applies to very high frequencies (or very long wires)

Comment: @Guy Inchbald, I just wanted to make sure that my reasoning was correct, and more importantly, to find a way to calculate this effect. It may seem obvious once you know, but it is not when you've never heard of it.